# AWS - Amazon Device Farm compatibility with Appium tests in NodeJS for iOS devices

Tags: node.js, testing, appium, appium-ios, aws-device-farm

I am planning on using Amazon Device Farm to deploy my Appium tests I have written but I am not sure if it is possible to use.

I have written my tests in NodeJS for iOS devices but every article I have read is either for java tests or Android.

Is there a way to deploy Appium tests written for iOS in NodeJS?
If not can you recommend an alternative App Farm that might be compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Device Farm has launched support for running Appium Node and Appium ruby based tests.
Please check our documentation for more details

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/aws-device-farm-now-supports-appium-nodejs-and-appium-ruby/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-node.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-ruby.html